# How to cancel an alarm function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I was making a little thing for time counting. I defined a function to achieve that. But I want the time counting machine to stop when I click the button. Is there any way to do that?

Can I define another function to stop the time-counting function or do any other thing to achieve that?

My code is:

```
from Tkinter import *
counter=0

def label_counter(label):
    def count():
        global counter
        counter+=1
        label.config(text=str(counter))
        label.after(1000,count)
    count()


root=Tk()
label=Label(root)
label.pack()
label_counter(label)

button=Button(root,text='Stop',command=root.destroy)
button.pack()

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest fix in your code is to assign an identifier to the alarm using another global variable:

```
from Tkinter import *
counter=0
alarm_id = None

def label_counter(label):

    def count():
        global counter
        global alarm_id
        counter+=1
        label.config(text=str(counter))
        alarm_id = label.after(1000,count)
    count()
```

Then you can create another button, and cancel the alarm using the `after_cancel` method (listed [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm)):

```
label.after_cancel(alarm_id)
```

Note that you should not be using global variables. Create a class and use its fields instead.